# What do Montaigne, Paine, and Wittgenstein have in common?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, wittgenstein, skepticism

> What do philosophers Michel de Montaigne (1533-1592), Thomas Paine
>   (1736-1809), and Ludwig Wittgenstein (1889-1951) have in common?

I found this question scribbled in the margin of a library copy of Montaigne's essays, and I wonder what the answer could be.

Comment: Some forms of [skepticism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/skepticism/) ...

Answer (score 1):

What do Montaigne, Paine, and Wittgenstein have in common?
About Paine, I do not know.
On LW and MM, the connection is obvious: both recognize that no general system can encompass all of philosophy. But they address the point from different stands: MM goes easy: his essays show that we can not grasp any law about anything (especially things ethical). LW goes the hard way: he states the same but, as he can not find an answer, he suffers.
But the basic aim remains: how to live a good life?
The answer lies not in words, not in discourse, but in acting, in seeing trough.

Comment: While I know that narratives are hard to source, but would you perhaps at least try to find some kind of quote or at least paper or book title in order to substantiate your analysis?

Comment: "Return to Reason", Stephen Toulmin, and "Philosopher Depuis Montaigne et Après Wittgenstein", Christian Cavaillé.